# The code of the build-in Scheme procedure "pair?"

Tags: scheme, built-in

I started to study the Scheme and curious of how the built-in procedure "pair?" works. I mean the code obviously, since I couldn't find a way to see the code of the built-in procedures and don't know how to write it I'm here.
Had the same question with the "List?" procedure but managed to write it myself, but in case of "pair?" have no idea. Thx!

Comment: Sounds like you want to take a look at the source code of the scheme implementation you're using. So ... what scheme implementation are you using? :)

Comment: Yes,sir! DrRacket)

Comment: `pair?` in Racket (I don't know about scheme) is a primitive. Each `Scheme_Object *` has a tag that says what type it is. `pair?` looks at that tag and returns `#t` if it matches the value for pair types.

Comment: so it means that's a primitive and we can't define it another way?

Comment: @Dmitrii The very first Scheme implementation was an interpreter under a Lisp 1.5 decendant similar to Common Lisp but without lexical scope (interlisp). Thus Scheme were the first lisp language with lexical scope. It's `pair?` just borrowed interlisp `consp`. From a working lexical lisp you can make the `cons` contract with vectors or closures. From internals of an implementation it can be done in serveral other ways that are far more effiecent. Bootstrapping a new lisp usually means making the primitives work by themselves so pairs would often be implemented in the host language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the implementation of the 'pair?' primitive in Racket. If so: it's currently in `list.c`:

https://github.com/racket/racket/blob/master/racket/src/racket/src/list.c

Specifically, look at the definition of `pair_p_prim`.

Hope this helps!

EDIT: why isn't it written in Racket?

Answer: `pair?` is a primitive in Racket and Scheme. This means that in Racket, it's not implemented in Racket, it's implemented in the language that Racket is implemented in. For this part of the language, that's C. Keep in mind that this can change; if the Racket implementation gets updated to provide a lower-level set of primitives, then the `pair?` function might no longer be a primitive. Finally, it's worth noting that for some languages, implementors leverage the existence of an older compiler in order to provide a 'bootstrapping' implementation where the implementation language is the same as the language
being developed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: no, its not what I want. I need the code of how the procedure works. Here is an example.The built-in procedure "list?" may be defined like that. (define (list? p)
(if (null? p)
true
(if (pair? p)
(list? (cdr p))
false))). I need the same definition for the procedure "pair?"

Comment: Thx! That really helped!

Answer (score 0):

`pair?` can be implemented in Scheme; Scheme is Turing complete, my friend!

But instead of doing your hw for you and to get your head spinning I will encode `pair?` in the lambda calculus using Scheme; from here, follow the white rabbit!

```
cpair? = λm. m (λx. λy. tru) fls
```

In Scheme:

```
(define c-pair? 
  (lambda (m) 
    ((m (lambda (x) (lambda (y) tru))) (lambda (x) fls))))

(define tru 
  (lambda (t) (lambda (f) t)))

(define fls
  (lambda (t) (lambda (f) f)))
```

Procedures for testing:

```
(define kons 
  (lambda (h)
    (lambda (t)
      (lambda (c) 
        (lambda (n)
          ((c h) ((t c) n)))))))

(define c-equal?
  (lambda (m) 
    (lambda (n) 
      ((c-and (iszero ((m prd) n)))
              (iszero ((n prd) m))))))

 (define c-and
   (lambda (b) 
     (lambda (c) 
       ((b c) fls))))

 (define iszero (lambda (m) ((m (lambda (x) fls)) tru))) 

 (define prd (lambda (m) (fst ((m ss) zz))))

 (define fst (lambda (p) (p tru)))

 ;; church-boolean -> real boolean
 (define real-bool (lambda (b) ((b true) false)))

 (define nil (lambda (c) (lambda (n) n)))

 ;; representation of number 1
 (define c1 (lambda (s) (lambda (z) (s z))))
```

Test:

```
 ;; some list - in Scheme this would be: (cons 1 '())
 (define d ((kons c1) nil)

 (real-bool ((c-equal? (c-pair? d)) tru)) ;; -> #t
 (real-bool ((c-equal? (c-pair? c1)) fls)) ;; -> #f
```

In other words; you can definitely write `pair?` in Scheme even if `pair?` is a primitive.

Comment: Care to explain this a bit? I tried the code in Chez and it doesn't work. Tried the `tru` and `fls` (for true and false) in Racket -- `fls` doesn't work. Thanks for the effort, though.